# Pyspark nested json with dynamical column names into one column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-schema

Could you help me? I need from this JSONL data:

```
{"id": 1, "data": {"key:1": {"string_value": "value_1"}, "key:2": {"string_value": "value_2"}, "user_id": {"string_value": "value_4"}}}
{"id": 2, "data": {"key:3": {"string_value": "value_3"}, "user_id": {"string_value": "value_5"}}}
```

get this data. Output should look like this:
[image]

Right now I'm using this solution:

```
output = df.select("id", "data.*")
output.show(200, False)
output.printSchema()
```

Im getting this data:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|id |key:1    |key:2    |key:3    |user_id  |
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|1  |{value_1}|{value_2}|null     |{value_4}|
|2  |null     |null     |{value_3}|{value_5}|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- key:1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key:2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key:3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is the [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) function. This is how you can use it:

First of all you need a `MapType` or `ArrayType` in order to apply the explode function. By default, when you read a jsonl with spark, it produces a `StructType`, as you can see with `printSchema()`.

```py
>>> df = spark.read.json('data.json')                  
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key:1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key:2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key:3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Applying an schema with `MapType` this is the output:

```
>>> schema = StructType() \
...     .add("data",
...         MapType(StringType(), StructType().add("string_value", StringType())), False) \
...     .add("id", StringType(), False)
>>> df = spark.read.json('data.json', schema=schema)                  
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

Now that we have a `map` we can use `explode`:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>>
>>> df.withColumn('user_id', F.expr('data.user_id.string_value')) \
...     .select('id', F.explode('data'), 'user_id').show()
+---+-------+---------+---------+
| id|    key|    value|  user_id|
+---+-------+---------+---------+
|  1|  key:1|{value_1}| value_4 |
|  1|  key:2|{value_2}| value_4 |
|  1|user_id|{value_4}| value_4 |
|  2|  key:3|{value_3}| value_5 |
|  2|user_id|{value_5}| value_5 |
+---+-------+---------+---------+
```

When you use `explode` it produces a row per map key. That's the reason there is a row for each `user_id` key. You can use `filter` to get rid of them:

```
>>> df.withColumn('user_id', F.expr('data.user_id.string_value')) \
...     .select('id', F.explode('data'), 'user_id') \
...     .withColumn('value', F.expr('value.string_value')) \
...     .filter('key != "user_id"').show()
+---+-----+---------+---------+
| id|  key|    value|  user_id|
+---+-----+---------+---------+
|  1|key:1| value_1 | value_4 |
|  1|key:2| value_2 | value_4 |
|  2|key:3| value_3 | value_5 |
+---+-----+---------+---------+
```

I hope I could help you. Bye!

Comment: Hi, that works, but in my case i need to change column type (to MapType()) in existing DF. maybe you know how to do in? Not in load(schema=schema) function? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey, sure! You can use create_map. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.create_map.html